# Spark view engine with array of namevaluepair

Tags: c#, syntax, template-engine, spark-view-engine, keyvaluepair

I would like to use the Spark view engine (DirectUse) for email templating. So I have dived into the Spark examples (EmailOrTextTemplating). But what I want is to use an array of NameValuePair(String name, object value) objects in the viewdata as a dictionary.

And then use this in the template like this:

```
<p>Name = ${#namevaluepairs["name"]}</p>
```

or

```
<if condition='namevaluepairs["date"].ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") == "31-01-2013"'>
  <p>text</p>
</if>
```

I don't know what the correct syntax is or how to put the namevaluepairs in the viewdata.
Can anyone help me in the right direction?

Ps I read the documentation but I see different ways of using the spark engine syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ViewData object *is* a dictionary.

Just load your objects into ViewData before calling Spark:

```
var engine = new SparkViewEngine();
var descriptor = new SparkViewDescriptor()
            .AddTemplate( templateFileName );
ISparkEngineView view = engine.CreateInstance( descriptor ) as ISparkEngineView;

view.ViewData["name"] = "foo";
view.ViewData["date"] = DateTime.Now;

view.RenderView( writer );
```

then in the template use ViewData like you normally would:

```
${ViewData["name"]}

<if condition='ViewData["date"]...'></if>
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I needed. But is it also possible to use namevaluepairs directly without the viewdata? i.e. ${name} This way the template is much cleaner to use.

Comment: You could use a strongly typed model, but that isn't name/value pairs. I believe you could also use dynamics, but not completely sure on that one.